# Font weight lighter after PHP function (Safari)

Tags: php, css

Only in Safari, after clicking on add to cart, font becomes so light to be almost unreadable. The problem persists as long as there is something in the basket, removing the products from the cart font returns to display properly.

```
body{font-smoothing:antialiased;
     -moz-font-smoothing:antialiased;
     -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
     -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
     -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
    }
```

This is my website:

http://edenelements.altervista.org

THE PAGE IS SHOP

Comment: your page don't found (404)

Comment: This sounds like a very interesting problem, however the link looks like you're trying to lead us to an actual shopping page. Do we need to log in, provide our details etc and buy some stuff before the problem becomes visible? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The page itself shows the problem, you just need to click add to cart in Safari. No registration is required to see the bug.

Comment: It is not a good idea to redirect users to your website to find the issue. Please make a jsfiddle with minimal code to reproduce the issue.